# How to change the text color of the bottom menu item?

Tags: android, menuitem

How to change the text color of the bottom menu item?

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: see my answer..!!

Comment: the item text display black color on the upper right side menu but display white on the bottom menu.

Comment: Instead of displaying in the action bar, the menu display on the bottom if the menu key tapped. Old devices still have menu key like Samsung S4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the the text color from `values>>Color.xml`

```
   <item name="android:ColorPrimary">#000000</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
   <item name="android:attr/textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
```

you can put you own color code in it. In my case I have put it Black(#000000)

IF this dnt work try to change the `Accent Color` from the same color.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000</item>
   <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">#000</item>
```

Struggled a bit with it, but the above eventually worked (on my KitKat phone not sure about other APIs)

Just remember to apply it to main theme and custom theme.